# Rewrite/simplify a trigonometric expression (electrical AC)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to rewrite the trig expression:

## Problem

$\frac{1}{2}\left ( \cos( \theta -\gamma) +\cos (2\omega t+\theta +\gamma ) \right )=....\text{should become....}=\frac{1}{2}\left [ \cos( \theta -\gamma)(1+ \cos (2\omega t+2\theta))   + \sin( \theta -\gamma)\sin (2\omega t+2\theta) \right ]$

## My attempt to solve it:

If I assume $\alpha=\omega t+\theta  \quad and \quad \beta=\omega t +\gamma$

then $\alpha -\beta=\theta -\gamma \text{  and  } \alpha +\beta=2\omega t+\theta +\gamma  $

So I can use the trig forumla: $\cos (\alpha +\beta)=\cos (\alpha)\cos (\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$

From the first row: $ \frac{1}{2}\left ( \cos( \alpha -\beta) +\cos (\alpha +\beta) \right )=\frac{1}{2}\left ( \cos( \alpha -\beta) + \cos (\alpha)\cos (\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) \right )$

But I get stuck here, I am supposed to get the $\sin(2\alpha)$ somehow?

Comment: You can ignore a $\cos(\theta-\gamma)$ term since it appears in both places. "All you need to do" is show that $$\cos(2\omega t+\theta+\gamma)=\cos(\theta-\gamma)\cos(2\omega t+2\theta)+\sin(\theta-\gamma)\sin(2\omega t+2\theta)$$
But the right-hand side is of the form $\cos p \cos q+\sin p \sin q$, so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that it can be resolved.

1. Do '$+\theta - \theta$'.
2. Take $\alpha =2\omega t+2\theta$ and $\beta=\gamma-\theta$.
3. Apply $cos(\alpha + \beta) = cos(\alpha)cos(\beta) - sin(\alpha)sin(\beta)$.
4. Finally, common factor and apply $sin(a) = -sin(-a)$.
   $$\frac{1}{2}\left ( \cos( \theta -\gamma) +\cos (2\omega t+\theta +\gamma ) \right )=\\
   =\frac{1}{2}\left ( \cos( \theta -\gamma) +\cos (2\omega t+2\theta - \theta  +\gamma ) \right )=\\
   =\frac{1}{2}\left [ \cos( \theta -\gamma)+ \cos( \theta -\gamma) \cos (2\omega t+2\theta))   - \sin( \gamma-\theta )\sin (2\omega t+2\theta) \right ]=\\
   =\frac{1}{2}\left [ \cos( \theta -\gamma)(1+ \cos (2\omega t+2\theta))   - \sin( \gamma-\theta )\sin (2\omega t+2\theta) \right ]=\\
   =\frac{1}{2}\left [ \cos( \theta -\gamma)(1+ \cos (2\omega t+2\theta))   + \sin( \theta -\gamma)\sin (2\omega t+2\theta) \right ]$$

Comment: Thank you so much!